# characterController reference issue

Tags: movement, raycasting, unity

I am trying to move my character to point that taken from mouse position.

here is my code:

```
private Vector3 hittedPoint=Vector3.zero;



 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
             Ray ray = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
             RaycastHit hit;


         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
             //get object
             GameObject hittedObject=hit.transform.gameObject;

             if(hittedObject==GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Ground")[0]){


                 hittedPoint= new Vector3(hit.point.x,transform.position.y,hit.point.z);
                 //hittedPoint = transform.TransformDirection (hittedPoint);


             }
         }
     }

             if (hittedPoint != Vector3.zero) {
                 float delta = (transform.position - hittedPoint).magnitude;
                 if (delta > 5) {
             controller.Move (hittedPoint*Time.deltaTime);
             Debug.Log (transform.position);
                 } else {
                     hittedPoint = Vector3.zero;
                     }
             }
```

The problem is that my object moves according to its first position at the scence. For example if I move character towards right then towards forward; at second movement it goes diagonal. It is like it makes its movements according the first position of it in scence.

The second problem is; i couldn't find efficient method for stopping movement when character reaches the point. If I decrease delta; character skips the point and if I increase it, character stops to early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`controller.Move((  hittedPoint - transform.position)*speed*Time.deltaTime);`

to solve the two problems. Speed is for second problem. Decrese it as you get closer to target.